# Java springboot in pcf

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am running Spring Boot application, when i am deploying a service into PCF, i am getting below error:

> ERROR Finalize failed with exception RuntimeError: No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation. >

I am using Java 1.8+ in my project, how can i know what is available in build pack/s in PCF env?

Looking for help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add additional tags to your question to cover the PCF / springbott environment, otherwise those with the relevant skills will not spot the question. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at the description, on `cf push`, the spring boot app jar file is not found. Check your path.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and close it?

Answer (score 2):

For checking the available buildpacks, you can use following command:
cf buildpacks

Output is as follows:
[image]

I'll briefly explain how the buildpack works as this would explain you the reason for the error you are getting.
Every buildpack has 3 scripts:

- detect
- compile
- release

When we push an application, ***detect script*** is called for all the buildpacks available, the first one to exit with 0 will be used for the application.

The error which you got shows that there was no matching buildpack which returned 0

You can push you application in the following manner:

1. Use *cf push and use -b flag* to specify the buildpack Use the
   manifest and specify the application path, buildpack and other
   details in it
2. ***cf push with -f flag*** lets you push your
   application with the details being read from the manifest.yml

> My preferred way is to use manifest.yml as it helps to centralize all
>   the tasks.

Refer: [Cloud Foundry manifest](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#buildpack)